# How do I filter my list results by the user logged on using angularJS in SharePoint2013

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, sharepoint-2013

This is my first time posting a question so please forgive me ignorance.

**Overview**: I am currently pulling SharePoint 2013 list data using a REST pull to return JSON data. Below is my JS and HTML.

**Problem**: I need to filter the data to only display the items which were created by user who is logged in. The end result I am working towards is a page where only the items created by the user who is logged in are displayed in a table.

**JS**:

```
    var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);   
    myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http){   
        $http({
            method: 'GET',   
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ITEquipmentRequests')/items?$select=*",   
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}   
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.customers = data.d.results;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="spCustomerController">   

    <table id="requestTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered"> 

        <tr id="requestTableHeader">   
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Supervisor</th>
            <th>Section Chief</th>
            <th>ISO</th>
            <th>Pentad</th>
            <th>FCIO</th>
            <th>Status</th> 
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">   
            <td class="col-md-4"><a ng-href="/PHX_IRM/ITEquip/ITEquipmentRequests/{{customer.Title}}">{{customer.Title}}</a></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><img class="statusIcon" src="{{customer.TextPicture}}" alt="Status"></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><img class="statusIcon" src="{{customer.SectionChief}}" alt="Status"></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><img class="statusIcon" src="{{customer.ISO}}" alt="Status"></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><img class="statusIcon" src="{{customer.Pentad}}" alt="Status"></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><img class="statusIcon" src="{{customer.FCIO}}" alt="Status"></td>
            <td class="col-md-2">{{customer.Status}}</td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
</div>
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider the following options:

**Filter list items via CAML query**

Filter list items via CAML query. Only the items that satisfy the query will be returned from the server, for that purpose replace the request:

```
$http({
       method: 'GET',   
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ITEquipmentRequests')/items?$select=*",   
       headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}   
})
```

with

```
//request endpoint
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";
//construct CAML query to return list items created by current user
var queryXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
//query payload
var queryPayload = { 
   'query':{ 
       '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
       'ViewXml': queryXml
    } 
}; 



$http({
       method: "POST",
       url : endpointUrl,
       data: queryPayload,  
       headers: {
               "Content-Type" : "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value 
       }          
})
```

Explanation:

CAML query is invoked via POST reqest using the following endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listTitle>')/getitems
```

> From performance perspective it represents the best approach.

**Using Angular `filter`**

Replace the line:

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
```

with

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter : isCurrentCustomer">
```

and declare `isCurrentCustomer` function in controller like this:

```
$scope.isCurrentCustomer = function(customer){
    return (customer.AuthorId == _spPageContextInfo.userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the results on client side, you can use the angular filter in your repeater.

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter : customer == loggedInUser">
```